# Do these courses fall under theoretical computer ccience

Tags: graphs, logic, information-theory

I am planning to apply for master's degree at TU Berlin and have to take some courses on theoretical computer science since the university requires me to take some credits on theoretical computer science.Do these courses come under this category?

1-Graph theory:Basic definitions, trees, Cayley's formula, connectedness, Eulerian and Hamiltonian graphs, matchings, edge and vertex colouring, chromatic numbers, planar graphs, directed graphs, networks.

2-Mathematical logic:Propositional and quantificational logic, formal grammar, semantical interpretation, formal deduction, completeness theorems, selected topics from model theory and proof theory.

3-Set theory:Sets, relations, functions, order, set-theoretical paradoxes, axiom systems for set theory, axiom of choice and its consequences, transfinite induction, recursion, cardinal and ordinal numbers.